# Using dependencies from yii client script in JS frameworks

Tags: php, yii, karma-runner, clientscript

I use **Yii Client Script** for rendering, loading Javascript and CSS files.
I am going to use **karma - runner** to test my Javascript modules

There are many libraries and dependencies that set in Yii Client Script in my application.

I'd like to know what the way I can set my Yii Client Script dependencies (javascript files) to karmaconfig.js file to execute my tests. Or perhaps there is another way to go.

I am also using PhantomJS with karma-runner. I don't know how to execute my tests and Client Script dependencies through Yii Console Command.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure it in `main.php` config file like below:

```
'clientScript'=>array(
    'packages'=>array(
        'karmaconfig'=>array(
            'baseUrl'=>'//YourBaseUrl',
            'js'=>array('karmaconfig.js'),
            'coreScriptPosition'=>CClientScript::POS_HEAD
        ),
        'otherScript'=>array(
            'baseUrl'=>'//YourOtherScriptBaseUrl',
            'js'=>array('yourOtherScript.js'),
            'depends'=>array('karmaconfig'), //THE POINT IS HERE TO DEFINE DEPENDENCY
            'coreScriptPosition'=>CClientScript::POS_BEGIN
         )
    ),
),
```

Then simply:

```
Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript('otherScript');
```

Then, as `otherScript` depends on `karmaconfig` script, Yii will automatically load `karmaconfig` script.

Comment: Maybe this is what I need. I am new with Yii. But I also need to execute "karma" command in Yii Command Console (it is from karma - runner library).